# What weapons have the Reach property?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, reach

Is there a comprehensive list of all weapons with Reach? The PHB lists a few however I have heard rumors that a spear and or staff had an errata to add Reach, but I cannot find a source for that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### The Martial Melee Weapons Table lists all the weapons with Reach.

These weapons are:

- Glaive
- Halberd
- Lance
- Pike
- Whip

This table can be found [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#MartialMeleeWeapons) in the Basic Rules or listed in [this DNDBeyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment?filter-search=reach&filter-cost-min=&filter-cost-max=&filter-weight-min=&filter-weight-max=).

The Reach property has never been added or removed from any weapon, as evidenced by [this](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) most recent printing of the *Player's Handbook Errata*.

Comment: It may be worth addressing the errata concern. Presumably by linking to the most recent errata (and describe where that could be found) and say what it says about reach.

Comment: thank you, i was confused because the polearm master feat was changed, but that didn't inherently add reach